# insert a new animation between loop animation

Tags: rendering, animation, rigging, game-engine, transforms

If I animation walk in circles. Can I insert the animation to walk out of the circle to a specific point and then return to walk around the circle at the same point?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You should be able to do it with the Nonlinear Animation editor